# TYPO3: Make part of TypoScript non-cacheable

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Is it possible to make a part of a "normal" TypoScript non-cacheable in TYPO3?

I don't call a PHP function immediately, so I cannot use `USER_INT`. What I want to achieve is to make the following thing non-cacheable:

```
80 = TEXT
80.value = foo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But you can use `COA_INT`:

```
80 = COA_INT
80 {
    10 = TEXT
    10.value = foo
}
```